# PHP session does not update via ajax request using IE9 and Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, internet-explorer-9

I have a CodeIgniter (CI) app that makes a jquery .ajax() request from page1 to page2 in the same app.

```
 $('.makecall').click(function() {
        mkcall = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: mkcall,
            success: function(data) {
                currentcall = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                $("#CurrentNumber").html("Current call: "+currentcall.number);
            }
        })
    return false;
    })
```

Page2 updates the session using CI's session class.

```
$svars = array('script_did' => $opt['number']['number']);
$this->session->set_userdata($svars);
```

This works beautifully in Firefox/Chrome but in IE9 the session values don't get added. The  javascript executes fine and there are no errors in the console so it seems to really be a problem with IE9 or CI session library.

How can I get IE9 to take the valeus?

Answer (score 0):

What is your CI session name? Per [this discussion](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/189641/) it appears that IE9 doesn't like underscores in the session name so make sure to remove the underscore if present.

```
// Change this:
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
// to, IE does not like the underscore!
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'cisession';
```